# Issue with accessing masks when training Unet model (valueError) coming up in case of scikit

Tags: image, scikit-learn, scikit-image, unet-neural-network

As can be seen below, the following code was used when training a Unet model through Spyder. I ended up taking a look at a Youtube tutorial by DigitalSreeni,in episode 208 where he looked at multi class semantic segmentation with the help of a Unet neural network. I recreated everything except the images (which are my own), but with the same dimensions, etc. Can anyone let me know what the issue is?

```
from simple_multi_unet_model import multi_unet_model #Uses softmax 

from keras.utils import normalize
import os
import glob
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


#Resizing images, if needed
SIZE_X = 128 
SIZE_Y = 128
n_classes=5 #Number of classes for segmentation

#Capture training image info as a list
train_images = []

for directory_path in glob.glob("/Hydro/128bit/images/"):
    for img_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.tif")):
        img = cv2.imread(img_path, 0)       
        #img = cv2.resize(img, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X))
        train_images.append(img)
       
#Convert list to array for machine learning processing        
train_images = np.array(train_images)

#Capture mask/label info as a list
train_masks = [] 
for directory_path in glob.glob("/Hydro/128bit/masks/"):
    for mask_path in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory_path, "*.tif")):
        mask = cv2.imread(mask_path, 0)       
        #mask = cv2.resize(mask, (SIZE_Y, SIZE_X), interpolation = cv2.INTER_NEAREST)  #Otherwise ground truth changes due to interpolation
        train_masks.append(mask)
        
#Convert list to array for machine learning processing          
train_masks = np.array(train_masks)

###############################################
#Encode labels... but multi dim array so need to flatten, encode and reshape
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
labelencoder = LabelEncoder()
n, h, w = train_masks.shape
train_masks_reshaped = train_masks.reshape(-1,1)
train_masks_reshaped_encoded = labelencoder.fit_transform(train_masks_reshaped)
train_masks_encoded_original_shape = train_masks_reshaped_encoded.reshape(n, h, w)


File "C:\Users\anish\208_multiclass_Unet_sandstone.py", line 63, in <module>
n, h, w = train_masks.shape
```

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: source video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XyX5HNuv-xE&list=PLZsOBAyNTZwbR08R959iCvYT3qzhxvGOE&index=13

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: The error message implies that `train_masks` is a 1D array, where it is expected to be a 3D array. I'd suggest investigating why it is 1D.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I did exactly that -- problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. It was returning 1d array because glob.glob function was not working properly and was not even returning the image list.